# RegisterClassEx Fails as Invalid Parameter - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, registerclass

A call to `RegisterClassEx` in my application is failing with error code 87, "The parameter is incorrect."

```
memset( &m_wcx, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) );

m_wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);  // size of structure
m_wcx.style = WS_ICONIC;            // initially minimized
m_wcx.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;       // points to window procedure
m_wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;               // no extra class memory
m_wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;               // no extra window memory
m_wcx.hInstance = m_hInstance;      // handle to instance
m_wcx.hIcon = ::LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION ); // default app icon
m_wcx.hCursor = ::LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW ); // standard arrow cursor
m_wcx.hbrBackground = NULL;         // no background to paint
m_wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;          // no menu resource
m_wcx.lpszClassName = _pwcWindowClass; // name of window class
m_wcx.hIconSm = NULL;               // search system resources for sm icon

m_atom = ::RegisterClassEx( &m_wcx );

if ( m_atom == 0 )
{
    TRACE(_T("CNotifyWindow::CNotifyWindow : Failed to register window class.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    THROW(::GetLastError());
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me which line is 87?

Comment: @Ramilol:  Pretty much the only line it could be is the call to RegisterClassEx.  Indeed, OP says that this is the line that is failing.

Comment: @Ramilol, `87` is the error code, not the line number.

Comment: BTW it's not the answer to the question, but if you're writing a standalone app you can get the app's `HINSTANCE` from `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`. (In fact all the `WinMain` arguments are junk these days, but the `HINSTANCE` is the one that is most annoying if you feel you have to pass around everywhere.)

Comment: I agree.  You can just declare it as global variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style` member of the [WNDCLASSEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633577%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure accepts [class styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729176%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), not [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28VS.85%29.aspx). In other words, you can't make all windows of that class initially minimized that way.

You should pass `WS_ICONIC` in the `dwStyle` argument to [CreateWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [CreateWindowEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: However, this might not be the actual problem is WS_ICONIC evaluates to something that would be a valid class style.

Comment: +1. This does stink of invalid flags being passed in. Look at the CS_* flags instead for the style parameter.

Comment: @John, I checked, `WS_ICONIC` is `0x20000000`, far higher than the highest class style bit (`CS_DROPSHADOW` at `0x20000`).

Answer (score 0):

Usually "The parameter is incorrect" is the WINAPI's way of saying, "dude, you're sending me crap."

So one of the `WNDCLASSEX` member variables is probably crap.  Start by taking a closer look at the variables that are most likely to have something inappropriate in them:  `m_wcx.hInstance`, `m_wcx.lpfnWndProc`, and `m_wcx.lpszClassName`.

### EDIT:

As pointed out by @Johann Gerell, `m_wcx.style = WS_ICONIC` is an example of this.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633577%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) says that this is a [class style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729176%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but you've sent a [window style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28VS.85%29.aspx).  No good.

What's the difference?  Well, you know the difference between a C++ `class` and an object, right?  A `class` is like a blueprint.  An object is an instantiation of that blueprint.  Same is true of Window Classes & Windows.  A Window Class is a blueprint for creating a window, and a window is an instantiation of that Window Class.  Window Classes have styles that specify things like what kind of DC to use, when to vertical refresh -- low level stuff like that which applies to every instance of that window class.  Windows also have styles, but these are different.  Window styles specify per-window things like if the window should be visible, minimized, etc.  So RegisterClassEx asked you for an orange, and you tried to give it an apple.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is the `WS_ICONIC`. The window **class** style is something entirely diferent from **window** style. The class styles are the `CS_*` ones.

Comment: To elaborate (this answer is very dry :) - `WS_ICONIC` is a window style. Pass it in to `CreateWindow` and friends. The style being specified in the `WNDCLASSEX` is a class style ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729176(v=VS.85).aspx )